# How to format a variable that comes from handlebar?

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm receiving this "$100.00 - $209.00" that comes from this handlebar (see 2nd line of code)

(that's a price range)

I need to format it, so it only shows the lowest price.

Unfortunately, I cannot format the original code and I need to format the code on HTML or something similiar.

My question is: Is there any way to format it after I receive it?

Thank you

```
<span class="price after_special>
 {{price<?php echo $priceKey; ?>_formated}}
</span>
```

That code returns $100.00 - $209.00
I need to have just $100

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the string using javascript's [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function. In below code regex will match:

- `^` - beginning of string
- `\$` - $ sign (needs to be escaped)
- `[0-9]*` - numbers from 0-9, `*` matches 0 or more numbers

The returned item is an array, so you need to get the first value using `[0]`.

```js
let price = '$100.00 - $209.00';
const regex = /^\$[0-9]*/;
let min = price.match(regex)[0];

console.log(min);
```

If you need to do it inside a template register a helper

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('getMinPrice', function(value) {
    return value.match(/^\$[0-9]*/)[0];
});

var t = Handlebars.compile($('#t').html());
$('body').append(t({
    _min_price: "$100.00 - $200.00"
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.1.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script id="t" type="text/x-handlebars">
    Before: {{_min_price}}
    After: {{getMinPrice _min_price}}
</script>
```

Comment: But I want to drop something like this->   {{price.match(/^\$[0-9]*/)[0]}}   in the code and doesn't let me do it. The problem that I have is actually that I don't have access to the place where the variable comes from. I need to fix it after I receive it.

Comment: Added an example how to register a helper and format the string in template